# Sum of one column based on two columns of dynamically value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following mysql table:

```
item code | warehouse | qty
---------------------------  
itm001    |    abc    |10  
itm002    |    xyz    |20  
itm003    |    pqr    |20  
itm004    |    pqr    |15  
itm001    |    abc    |60  
itm002    |    xyz    |10  
itm004    |    tqr    |20  
itm003    |    www    |20  
itm001    |    ppp    |15
```

I want sum of **when item code and warehouse repeat their qty total**:
for example:
itm001 abc is repeted two times their sum display itm001 = 70
same way for itm002 and display sum itm002 = 30.

I dont want static where clause (where item code = 'itm001' and warehouse = 'abc' or item code ='itm002' and warehouse = 'xyz').

Comment: Can you please clarify whether you wish to group rows with the same `itemcode, warehouse` + summed quantity as **one** new row, or whether you wish to repeat the original rows (possibly with additional columns) with the duplicated summed quantity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `GROUP BY` with `HAVING`:

```
SELECT itemcode,warehouse,SUM(qty) FROM yourtable
GROUP BY itemcode,warehouse
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

`HAVING` filters out the items that only exist once in a warehouse.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
  SELECT itemcode,warehouse,SUM(qty) FROM table1 GROUP BY warehouse,itemcode;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
SELECT item_code, warehouse,sum(qty)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY item_code, warehouse
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the havin clause on a group by.

```
select item_code, warehous, sum(qty), count(*)
group by item_code, warehouse 
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you can use: 
`SELECT item_code, warehouse , SUM(qty) FROM yourTable WHERE (...) GROUP BY item_code, warehouse;`